# What's the difference between Ubuntu's man and macOS's man?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, macos, man

My main machine is running macOS 14 Sonoma, but I often `ssh` into Ubuntu servers. Recently I noticed a strange difference between the `man` program on these platforms.

On Ubuntu, `man` displays a useful "prompt" in the bottom-left corner:
[image: ubuntu man]

It can be configured with the `--prompt` option - `man --prompt "hey unix stackexchange!" man` results in:

[image]

But on macOS, prompt is not there:

[image: macos man]

At first I thought that I may be simply using different versions of `man`. On Ubuntu `man --version` prints `man 2.11.2`, but on macOS this option doesn't exist:

```
$ man --version
/usr/bin/man: illegal option -- -
Usage:
 man [-adho] [-t | -w] [-M manpath] [-P pager] [-S mansect]
     [-m arch[:machine]] [-p [eprtv]] [mansect] page [...]
 man -f page [...] -- Emulates whatis(1)
 man -k page [...] -- Emulates apropos(1
```

Then I decided to see what the `man` executables really are, and the result surprised me.

On Ubuntu:

```
$ file $(which man)
/usr/bin/man: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=93e22c77b20c329ec51dad530c40fd0d64fc696f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

on macOS:

```
$ file $(which man)
/usr/bin/man: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
```

My questions are:

- why does `man` on Ubuntu (and probably on Debian and many other) differ so much from macOS's `man`?
- how can I have a more fully-featured `man` on macOS?

Comment: MacOS is not GNU.

Comment: Hmmm... let's see - how can I put this politely? Well, the truth is that macOS man pages mostly just suck. Disregarding for a moment that they (Apple) have never adopted `man-db`, many of their man pages are truly *vintage* - not updated in 20 years (e.g. `man ls`). The only salvation from this malfeasance is (e.g.) MacPorts. I love my Macs (have several), but I really do not care for their cavalier attitude toward the system manuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default version of `man` on most Linux distributions is [man-db](https://man-db.gitlab.io/man-db/), which is quite different from the default version of `man` on macOS. The macOS version is probably based on a BSD version.

You can install man-db on macOS using Homebrew or MacPorts; with the latter, run

```
sudo port install man-db
```